# Dynamic property needs to call __get__ explicitly (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I am experimenting with `property` in order to add attributes to an object at run-time. I have the code below (I know it's a bit crazy but I thought it would work):

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self['bar1'] = Bar()
        self['bar1'].value = property(self.value_bar1)
        self['bar1'].other_value = property(Bar.other_value_bar1)
        self['bar2'] = Bar()
        self['bar2'].value = property(self.value_bar2)
        self['bar2'].other_value = property(Bar.other_value_bar2)

    @staticmethod
    def value_bar1(instance):
        return 'I am bar1.'
    @staticmethod    
    def value_bar2(instance):
        return 'I am bar2.'

class Bar(object):
    def other_value_bar1(self):
        return 'I am the other bar1.'

    def other_value_bar2(self):
        return 'I am the other bar2.'

foo = Foo()
print(foo['bar1'].value.__get__(foo['bar1']))
print(foo['bar2'].value)
print(foo['bar1'].other_value.__get__(foo['bar1']))
print(foo['bar2'].other_value)
```

and it returns :

```
I am bar1.
<property object at 0x7f3e9338a1d8>
I am the other bar1.
<property object at 0x7f3e9338a228>
```

Could someone explain why I need to call the property's `__get__` method explicitly to get its value ?

Comment: Because you're creating a property on an instance, not on the class.

Comment: I see. In the actual code I was trying to get the two instances of `Bar` to compute the value of the same property according to two different formulae. I will probably have to think of another way. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps they should be instances of different subclasses of the same baseclass, then.

Comment: Absolutely, this sounds like the best way around. And that would also make the code easier to read !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by jonrsharpe, the code above creates a property on an instance, not on the class.

To remedy this, `Bar1` and `Bar2` can be subclasses of the same base class  like so:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self['bar1'] = Bar1()
        self['bar2'] = Bar2()

class BarBase(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.compute_value()

class Bar1(BarBase):
    def compute_value(self):
        return 'I am bar1.'

class Bar2(BarBase): 
    def compute_value(self):
        return 'I am bar2.'

foo = Foo()
print(foo['bar1'].value)
print(foo['bar2'].value)
```